# What are diffrences between wrk2 and Apache Benchmark (i.e. ab) tools?

Tags: tomcat, jersey, vert.x, wrk

Are there any significant difference between wrk2 and Apache's Benchmark (i.e. **ab**) for testing multi-threaded requests? If there are what are they?

I'm asking this based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56373673/6805866) answer and as I have to test Java RESTful Service Web CRUD app written in **SpringBoot** (uses **Apache Tomcat** web server), **Dropwizard** (uses **Jersey** web server) and **Vert.X** (web server is **part of it's own implementation** as much as I know, please **correct me if I'm wrong**) using **concurrent HTTP requests**.

Any advice/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: read these question/answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31174076/go-http-server-testing-ab-vs-wrk-so-much-difference-in-result